# How to pass one overload of a method group?

Tags: c#, delegates, method-group

**Edit:  It is my own mistake (combined with some unexpected changes outside).  please ignore this post and sorry for inconvenience!**

Before I used to just pass this method:

```
string DoSomething(string)
```

Now the vendor added another overload like void `DoSomething(string, string)`.  I tried to pass the method as a parameter but the compiler complains it `cannot convert the method group,` which makes sense I guess since `DoSomething` now has 2 signatures.

The question is, how do I pass just one `signature`?

Comment: Pass to what?  Give us an example.

Comment: I believe you did not write your code correctly. Could you paste a code snippet and we can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should define your parameters as either Action<string> or Action<string, string> depending on which method you wish to call.

[The Action<T> Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx)